# On a UITextView loaded from NIB, how can I customize the layout manager?

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

I know that there is an initializer for `UITextView` that takes a custom container which in turn can have a custom layout manager attached. But I would prefer to setup my text view from NIB instead.

How would I - most elegantly - customize the layout manager if the text view is loaded from NIB?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I don't think you can. Or at least you couldn't when TextKit first came out. Maybe that's improved since iOS 7